# google python class string1 exercise

Tags: python

I working on the string1 exercise that is a part of the Google Python class. The question I'm having problems with is C:

```
C. fix_start
Given a string s, return a string
where all occurences of its first char have
been changed to '*', except do not change
the first char itself.
e.g. 'babble' yields 'ba**le'
Assume that the string is length 1 or more.
Hint: s.replace(stra, strb) returns a version of string s
where all instances of stra have been replaced by strb.
```

I was thinking of use a loop to compare each letter with the first letter and replace any that match with '*'. I think there has to be an easier way though. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an easier way to do it, and the question already gives you a hint:

> `s.replace(stra, strb)` returns a version of string where all instances of `stra` have been replaced by `strb`.

Think about how you might use that function.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a hint provided, and it does not involve using a loop!

It suggests using `s.replace(stra, strb)` and describes what effect that would have, so given the problem statement lets look at what `s`, `stra`, and `strb` should be.

- We only want to replace occurrences *after* the first character, so the `s` in `s.replace(stra, strb)` should be everything from the second character on.  We can get this using the slice `s[1:]` (here `s` is the parameter passed into the function).
- Since we want to replace all occurrences of the first character, `stra` should be that first character, or `s[0]` (again `s` is the parameter).
- `strb` is easy, it says we are replacing the matches with `*`, so `strb` is `'*'`

So somewhere in your function, you will want `s[1:].replace(s[0], '*')`, that will get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I got, no loop required.

```
def fix_start(s):

  return s[0]+s[1:].replace(s[0], '*')
```

This only works considering they tell us we should assume the string is not ''.  In that case the return line should be moved to the body into an if and the len checked first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my longer solution. I broke the s up into 2 parts and worked the replace on the second part of the string the 'rest' of the word. It is longer but included here to show a thought process to solve the puzzle.

```
def fix_start(s):
  star = s[0]
  rest = s[1:]
  rest = rest.replace(star,'*')

  return star+rest
```